# Solr full text search is not working

Tags: solr, solrj

I am developing an application. I have to index all pdf, docx, links uploaded by various user. Indexing is working fine and it search the documents but it is not supporting full text search. When I am searching a word inside the pdf, it shows no result found. May I need to add some thing for Solr full text search in schema.xml?

I am new to solr so please help..

In schema, I have added these fields, and solr doing indexing on these fields,

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

but not doing full text search, and I am using solr-4.7.2

Comment: could you share the schema.xml because need to check what is the fieldType for your field text...?

Comment: <field name="module" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="createdTimestamp" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

These are the fields in my schema..

Comment: how are you doing indexing ? are you using DIH with tika? Can you share the data-config.xml?

Comment: I m not using data config.. indexing is performing through a document in which i am sending data to jms queue and receiving data as Json object, and then code is wriiten for indexing, and using HttpSolrServer

Answer (score 1):

Thanku but this error is solved when i have added following line in schema:

```
<dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
```

```
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" />
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```